# Идеoлогически верный ключ

Tags: sql

Предположим, что есть сущность, где уникальность каждой строки гарантируется совокупностью 4 колонок- эти колонки представляют собой PK из 4-ех других таблиц.

На эти 4 колонки из других таблиц будут вести внешние ключи. Чтобы в каждую зависимую таблицу не добавлять этот составной ключ, прокидывая портянку из 4-ех колонок, я делаю поле еще одно суррогатное поле с id и типом identity, на которое будут идти все внешние ключи.

Итак, что в данном случае идеoлогически верно сделать pk-таблицы, а что ak, повесив уникальный индекс?

Вроде, разницы в производительности особой быть не должно - > вопрос больше идеoлогический.

Comment: *На эти 4 колонки из других таблиц будут вести внешние ключи.* Неясно. Каждая slave-таблица референсится на всю совокупность из 4 полей, или только на одно из них?

Comment: *вопрос больше идеoлогический* Идеологически - для использования естественных ключей на реальных схемах, а не в учебной базе, нужно иметь более чем веские основания. Особенно когда в состав выражения естественного ключа входят поля неформализуемого типа (строки, в т.ч. бинарные и json/xml, дата-время высокой точности, decimal...).

Comment: @Akina Данные не естественные. Таблица является некоторой связующей сущностью нескольких таблиц. И вот, что бы не тянуть портянку из нескольких колонок в другие таблицы подумал еще один суррогатный ключ сделать, что бы только его прокидывать в зависимые таблицы.

Comment: @Akina 'Неясно. Каждая slave-таблица референсится на всю совокупность из 4 полей, или только на одно из них?' Каждая, так как составной ключ говорит о том, что по отдельности поля не могут быть уникальными, а делать референс не на уникальное поле(по крайней мере так в MS SQL) нельзя.

Comment: *составной ключ говорит о том, что по отдельности поля не могут быть уникальными* Составной **первичный** ключ - ничто не мешает ему быть совокупностью полей, каждое из которых по отдельности уникально. Ну так, ежели формально подходить...

Comment: *Данные не естественные. Таблица является некоторой связующей сущностью нескольких таблиц. И вот, что бы не тянуть портянку из нескольких колонок в другие таблицы подумал еще один суррогатный ключ сделать, что бы только его прокидывать в зависимые таблицы.* Вполне обычный и нормальный подход. Просто надо принять, что связь сама по себе является сущностью.

Comment: У вас путаница в терминологии. "эти колонки представляют собой PK из 4-х других таблиц" — вероятнее всего не «PK из …», а «FK на …». "На эти 4 колонки из других таблиц будут вести внешние ключи" — FK ссылается не на колонки, а на строку таблицы (средствами уникального ключа), или в терминах реляционной алгебры просто на таблицу.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Не вижу путаницы :) . Совокупность этих 4-ех колонок однозначно идентифицируют строчку в этой таблице => это PK или AK. А то, что каждая колонка из этих 4-ех в свою очередь по отдельности- это FK к другим таблицам- это уже дело десятое.

Answer (score 0):

> Итак, что в данном случае идеoлогически верно сделать pk-таблицы, а что ak, повесив уникальный индекс?

ПК - суррогатный ID, АК - естественный составной.

Даже в голову не могло прийти, что суррогатный ключ можно использовать как альтернативный, а не первичный.

Comment: *Даже в голову не могло прийти, что суррогатный ключ можно использовать как альтернативный, а не первичный.* По-моему, товарищ имел в виду только естественный PK, без суррогата вообще.

Comment: @Akina, тоже сначала так подумал, но потом перечитал три раза, и решил что создание ID для FK уже вопрос решенный.